# How to write a SQL query for this logic (has_many, belongs_to association)?

Tags: sql, mysql

The goal of this SQL query is to return the user with the most fight wins AND a count of the wins.

I have two tables: users and fights.

User has many fights
Fight belongs to user

Fight has the following columns of concern:

- challenger_id (user_id fk)
- challengee_id (user_id fk)
- challenger_won (boolean)

As you can see, a user can be a challenger or a challengee, but not both.

- If the user is a challenger and the challenger_won = true, then it is considered a win.
- If the user is a challengee and the challenger_won = false, then it is considered a win.
- If the challenger_won = null, then just disregard it.

How would I write the SQL for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT a.fighter, COUNT(*) AS wins
  FROM (SELECT challenger_id AS fighter
          FROM fights
         WHERE challenger_won = TRUE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT challengee_id AS fighter
          FROM fights
         WHERE challenger_won = FALSE
       ) AS a
 GROUP BY a.fighter;
```

If `challenger_won` is NULL, both queries in the UNION will ignore the row, as required.

If you don't like UNION ALL, you can use, instead:

```
SELECT a.fighter, SUM(a.wins) AS wins
  FROM (SELECT challenger_id AS fighter, 'R' AS role, COUNT(*) AS wins
          FROM fights
         WHERE challenger_won = TRUE
         GROUP BY fighter, role
        UNION
        SELECT challengee_id AS fighter, 'E' AS role, COUNT(*) AS wins
          FROM fights
         WHERE challenger_won = FALSE
         GROUP BY fighter, role
       ) AS a
 GROUP BY a.fighter;
```

The first part of the UNION generates rows with 'R' as role (for 'challengeR won') and the fighter ID and a count of the fights won.  The second part generates rows with 'E' as role (for 'challengeE won') and the fighter ID and a count of the fights won.  The role is necessary in case some fighter won 3 fights as challenger and 3 fights as challengee; without the role, the two entries with the same fighter and count would be collapsed into one.  You then sum the wins for each fighter in each role.

Comment: when i run the first query i get an error that says "every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @keruilin: guilty as charged - I've added the missing 'AS a' clauses (because if you added 'AS b' instead, then you'd get unknown table/alias 'a' errors.  I haven't run the code - as you can tell.